# Insert and Format text in android

Tags: android, xml, textview

**UPDATE: for those who are searching for answers, I found this tutorial, the BEST :**
[mobile.tutsplus.com](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/customize-android-fonts/)

I want to insert a `TextView` with a long text. How do I do that? Just insert it in `string.xml`?

Is there any way to format the text? Like: Font, color, alignment, space (like TabSpace - I don't know how it's called), paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use as below:

```
<string name="screen_lbl"><![CDATA[<FONT COLOR="#ff0000">Here</FONT><FONT COLOR="#ffffff">Enter Data</FONT>]]></string>
```

You can make use of `CDATA` in `strings.xml`

or if you want to do in java, make use of `Html.fromHtml()` as below:

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<u><b>"+Your String+"</b></u>"));
```

Comment: Do u find the solution @raulpop8

Comment: Thanks! It is working, but, what about importing new fonts? And if I am writing my text and need UTF-8 encoding (special characters - other language than English), do I need some special code? :)

Comment: If u want to encode to UTF-8, do like this: `String str= URLEncoder.encode("Your String", "UTF-8");` ... Can u please UPVOTE my answer....